# Simplifying the binomial expansion

Tags: binomial-theorem

I have $$-\frac{1}{2} \left[1-\frac{z}{2}+\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^2 -\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^3+...\right]$$

Why does this equal $-\frac{1}{2} \sum^\infty_{n=0} \left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^n$

and not $-\frac{1}{2} \sum^\infty_{n=0} (-1)^n\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^n$?
I think it is the latter because the signs alternate.

Comment: Did you mean $\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^2$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have corrected it

Comment: Is there any further information about $z$ available?

Comment: @jmoravitz corrected

Comment: In any case, ignoring the $-\frac{1}{2}$ out front for simplicity, assuming it is $1-\frac{z}{2} + (\frac{z}{2})^2-(\frac{z}{2})^3+(\frac{z}{2})^4 - \cdots + (\frac{z}{2})^{2k}-(\frac{z}{2})^{2k+1}+\cdots$, indeed it can be written as $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(\frac{z}{2})^n$.  It can also be written as $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{-z}{2})^n$ by combining the terms.  It is not however equal to $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{z}{2})^n$ unless $z=0$.

Comment: @onceuponacrinoid the question is to do with finding the laurent expansion of $f(z)=\frac{2z-5}{(z-2)(z-3)}$ in the disk $0 \leq |z| <2$. I   simplified f(z) using partial fractions to $\frac{1}{z-2}+\frac{1}{z-3}$.  Then in the question is the binomial expansion of $\frac{1}{z-2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct!

$$-\frac12 \left(1-\frac{z}{2}+\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^2\cdots\right)=-\frac12\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(z/2)^n=\frac{1}{z-2}$$

Note that $(-1)^n=1$ when $n$ is even, and $(-1)^n=-1$ when $n$ is odd.  So, the sign alternates with every other term starting with $+1$ at $n=0$.

Comment: so basically if the signs alternate then stick a $(-1)^n$

Comment: Note that $(-1)^n=1$ when $n$ is even, and $(-1)^n=-1$ when $n$ is odd.  So, the sign alternates with every other term starting with $+1$ at $n=0$.  For future reference, note that $1-(-1)^n =0$ for even $n$ and $2$ for odd $n$.

Comment: could we say that $-\frac{1}{2} \sum^\infty_{n=1} (-1)^n \left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^n$ converges for $\left|\frac{z}{2}\right|<2$?